# Autoresize textbox control vertically

Tags: c#, textbox, resize

In a C# form, I have a panel anchored all sides, and inside, a textbox, anchored top/left/right.

When text gets loaded into the textbox, i want it to auto expand itself vertically so that I don't need to scroll the textbox (scroll the panel at most, if there is more text that doesn't fit the panel).
is there any way to do this with a textbox? (i'm not constrained to use this control so if there's another control that fits the description, feel free to mention it)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'll assume this is a multi-line text box and that you'll allow it to grow vertically.  This code worked well:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Size sz = new Size(textBox1.ClientSize.Width, int.MaxValue);
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
        int padding = 3;
        int borders = textBox1.Height - textBox1.ClientSize.Height;
        sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font, sz, flags);
        int h = sz.Height + borders + padding;
        if (textBox1.Top + h > this.ClientSize.Height - 10) {
            h = this.ClientSize.Height - 10 - textBox1.Top;
        }
        textBox1.Height = h;
    }
```

You ought to do something reasonable when the text box is empty, like setting the MinimumSize property.

Comment: It workes but does not handle lines with no spaces. the one David wrote handles that

Comment: @Hans Passant What if it's a single-line textbox?

Comment: Then you don't care about the height of course, it is fixed.

Comment: This answer handles descenders on the last line of text correctly

Answer (score 35):

The current selected answer does NOT handle lines with no spaces such as "jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"x1000 (think about what would happen if someone pasted a URL)

This code solves that problem:

```
private void txtBody_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // amount of padding to add
    const int padding = 3;
    // get number of lines (first line is 0, so add 1)
    int numLines = this.txtBody.GetLineFromCharIndex(this.txtBody.TextLength) + 1;
    // get border thickness
    int border = this.txtBody.Height - this.txtBody.ClientSize.Height;
    // set height (height of one line * number of lines + spacing)
    this.txtBody.Height = this.txtBody.Font.Height * numLines + padding + border;
}
```

Comment: The best answer. Minor tweak: GetLineFromCharIndex() does not count trailing crlf, so check for that and add +1 if needed.

Comment: @amonroejj That's strange. I just tried this out and it's not necessary for me. I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: is this for .Net Core?

Comment: This answer handles empty lines etc well, but truncates descenders on the final line of text. I changed padding to 6, which works for my application, but is a bit of a frig really although it seems to work for font sizes 7pt to 48pt.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using [`Graphics.MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx).

First you create a `Graphics` object, then call `MeasureString` on it, passing the string and the textbox's font.

**Example**

```
string text = "TestingTesting\nTestingTesting\nTestingTesting\nTestingTesting\n";

// Create the graphics object.
using (Graphics g = textBox.CreateGraphics()) {        
    // Set the control's size to the string's size.
    textBox.Size = g.MeasureString(text, textBox.Font).ToSize(); 
    textBox.Text = text;
}
```

You could also limit it to the vertical axis by setting only the `textBox.Size.Height` property and using the `MeasureString` overload which also accepts `int width`.

**Edit**

As SLaks pointed out, another option is using [`TextRenderer.MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66(v=VS.100).aspx). This way there's no need to create a `Graphics` object.

```
textBox.Size = TextRenderer.MeasureString(text, textBox.Font).ToSize();
```

Here you could limit to vertical resizing using Hans' technique, passing an extra `Size` parameter to `MeasureString` with `int.MaxValue` height.

Comment: You forgot to dispose `g`.  You should call `TextRenderer.MeasureString`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Label, and set AutoSize to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You could anchor it to the bottom, that will ensure that the textbox is resized vertically when ever the form to which it belongs is resized.
Also, a textbox that changes its size might not be an elegant thing since it might disrupt the way that other components are displayed. Why don't you give it a maximum size instead of having it resized?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

**aspx.cs code**

```
protected int GetRows(object value) {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
            return 1;

        var contentTrimmed = value.ToString().Replace('\t', ' ').Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' ').Trim();

        var length = (decimal)contentTrimmed.Length;
        if (length == 0)
            return 1;

        int res = 0;
        decimal maxLength = 56;
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
        {
             SizeF sizeRef = graphics.MeasureString("W", new Font("Segoe UI", 13, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel));
             maxLength = maxLength * (decimal)sizeRef.Width;

             SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(contentTrimmed, new Font("Segoe UI", 13, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel));
             length = (decimal)size.Width;
        }

        res = (int)Math.Round(length / (decimal)maxLength, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        if (res == 0)
            return 1;

        return res;
 }
```

**aspx code**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" MaxLength="500" Width="700px" Rows='<%# GetRows(Eval ("Value")) %>' ></asp:TextBox>
```