# correct height of multi-line text windows form

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, desktop-application

How I can calculate correct height of text inside multi-line text-box and space around lines and text? I need to enable scrollbar programmatically.

Comment: You mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893059/autoresize-textbox-control-vertically

Comment: There are a couple of other methods discussed on different posts here on SO. I'm pretty sure one of them will have what you want (or as close to what you want as is possible). Good luck!

Comment: I think , I had already tried  for above link , TextRenderer.MeasureString(text, textBox.Font).ToSize(); but  maybe because of devexpress control not getting correct size

Comment: I am overriding text property of windows form text-box and enabling scrollbar in property if text exceeded height of text-box

Comment: TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl was explicitly designed to deal with the somewhat quirky way in which TextBox formats its text.  It is the oldest control in the toolbox, 30 years already, time hasn't been that kind to it.