# WinForms - get actual multiline TextBox height when vertical scrollbar is enabled

Tags: c#, winforms

let's say that we have a multiline `TextBox` into which a collection of `Lines` is added. `TextBox` has a `VerticalScrollbar` enabled so that it activates when the text content is too big for actual size of the `TextBox`.

By default, `Size` of `TextBox` is fixed.

Now, when text content bigger/longer than the `TextBox` area is loaded into `TextBox` I need to obtain the actual `Height` of the `TextBox` for currently displayed text content (Height which should allow to display the whole content without need of use the scrollbar).

`TextBox` has `WordWrap` enabled.

How can we do that?

Comment: Clarify:  you want to avoid the scrollbar by figuring out the height and then resizing it yourself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893326/17034

Comment: Well scrollbar should be present, but I need in some cases manually force the size of text area

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant that is exaclty what I need.